# Time series chart horizontal gridlines through min/max peaks

Tags: jfreechart, time-series, gridlines

I am using JFreeChart to plot a timeseries chart. The chart is working fine, but the gridline alignment is becoming a problem.

My requirement is to show the horizontal gridlines through the peak values (i.e for the max and min value). Could you please let me know if there is any property for this, as I am getting grids randomly.

Comment: A `TimeSeries` has methods to get the minimum and maximum values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `Marker` to highlight the min and max values?

[image]

As trashgod sugested you use the `Dataset` to get the minimum and maximum values and then add a `Marker` to the `Plot`

```
Range range = dataset.getRangeBounds(true);
plot.addRangeMarker(new ValueMarker(range.getLowerBound(),Color.GREEN,new BasicStroke(2.0f)),Layer.BACKGROUND);
plot.addRangeMarker(new ValueMarker(range.getUpperBound(),Color.BLUE,new BasicStroke(2.0f)),Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Could you please suggest the way to display the corresponding values in the axis.

Comment: @user1976862 use `Marker#SetLabel`

Comment: How are you drawing the red line starting from some x1 to x2 in your code? My graph has domain range (Xmin, Xmax). Need to draw line from X1 to X2 given, Xmin<X1<X2<Xmax.