# Mark current value on axis - jfreecharts

Tags: java, jfreechart, axis, renderer

I'm implementing dynamic charts with XYPlot and TimeSeries. I'm continually adding new values to chart. How can I mark on Y axis last added value? Some custom renderer or just simple change font size... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add a [`ValueMarker`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ValueMarker.html) to the plot via the [`addRangeMarker()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#addRangeMarker%28org.jfree.chart.plot.Marker%29) method.

This will typically add a line across the plot perpendicular to the y-axis, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336387/230513).